# Google is not defined.You have exceeded your request quota for this API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

При подключении карты на ней выбивается ошибка[image: При загрузке Google Карт на этой странице возникла проблема.]
И в консоли появляется такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ получил, вставил скрипт до body. Ограничений на квоты нет. В чём проблема?

```
  <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyChCae4udTMEmK6jR3Q46xCYJYAnnUlmmM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 52.0768871, lng: 23.7496443},
                zoom: 8,
            });
        }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0768871, 23.7496443),
            title: "title"
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: У вас скрипт загружается асинхронно. Вероятно, в этом проблема.

Comment: Как исправить не подскажите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что необходимо было активировать бесплатную версию API, указав платёжные данные. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0768871, 23.7496443),
    title: "title"
});
```

в основном потоке, не в callback `&callback=initMap`, но почему-то мой код выдает ошибку все равно.

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin
>   frame.

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 52.0768871, lng: 23.7496443},
          zoom: 8,
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0768871, 23.7496443),
          title: "title"
      });
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyChCae4udTMEmK6jR3Q46xCYJYAnnUlmmM&callback=initMap"></script>
```